# vertical-align img weird behaviour

Tags: html, css

I came across something which really confused me:

```css
.container{
  height: 200px;
}

img{
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.content{
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img src="https://www.dierendokters.com/images/stories/dierfoto/kitten%20kijkt%20omhog.jpg">
    <span class="content">content</span>
</div>
```

According to what I read `vertical-align` is used to align inline elements in a (not inline) parent container.

But why if I put the `vertical-align:middle;` on the img the text is centered in the middle of the `<img>`? And why isn't the `<img>`vertically aligned in the middle of the `<div>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you read applies to `inline-block` elements, and the vertical alignment refers to the alignment of the sibling elements to each other, i.e. along a line, not in reference to a block parent with fixed height.

```css
.container{
background: #ddd;
}

img{
height: 100px;
width: auto;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
}

.content{
height: 50px;
display: inline-block;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img src="https://www.dierendokters.com/images/stories/dierfoto/kitten%20kijkt%20omhog.jpg">
    <span class="content">content</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The image occupies the entire height of the line. It doesn't move no matter what value you use on `vertical-align`.

This is because the natural height of the image is taller than the height of the container.

```
image height: 216px vs. container height: 200px
```

However, changing the value on the image does force the baseline to shift.

The default value of `vertical-align` is baseline.

So, what is actually happening is that the text element – which is set to baseline alignment – is shifting vertically within the height of the line-box.

Use `vertical-align` on the text if you want to move it around.

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
}

.content {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://www.dierendokters.com/images/stories/dierfoto/kitten%20kijkt%20omhog.jpg">
  <span class="content">content</span>
</div>
```